# Does flutter support debug command like po in iOS development?

Tags: flutter

I am developing in Android Studio and it is not easy to debug my Flutter app. I am used to debugging in Xcode (iOS) and it is easy to examine a object with the `po` command. I was wondering if there is a similar command for Flutter in Android Studio?

Answer (score 0):

No. You can't. Maybe visual studio code is a little bit easy and fast as compare to android studio

Answer (score 0):

Of Course!, Run your Flutter app in the debugging mode and when the code hit the breakpoint. select `Evaluate Expression` [Expression window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zN8LB.png)